# What options exist to update Android app setting remotely?

Tags: android

I have an Android device that I'm using to monitor a couple of sensors with an app that I created.  What useful ways are there to update the settings in my app (while it's running at a remote location) from my computer?  I'm interested in sending a message to my app to tell it to email a screenshot, change sample rate, etc.  Creative workarounds are encouraged.

I've already looked into C2DM and unfortunately have no experience with setting up the required third-party application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] It just occurred to me that I may have grossly over simplified what you were trying to do. If this is the case my answer probably wont be of much if any help to you. The original answer follows though.

You could use TCP sockets to set up a client/server interface between your app and a command program on your computer. Then just send a set of predefined messages/commands. Two tutorials I used for learning this are [Here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication) and [Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/). This wont help with the computer side of the sockets code per se although if you write the computer program in Java it should effectively be the same. This is something we are doing at my company to create a custom command interface for a product we have in development.

Comment: You did not oversimplify what I was trying to do--this method works like a charm!  I used C# to interface with Android, and it does the job if Android is connected to the same Wifi network.  Any chance you've been successful connecting across two different networks in your development?

Comment: Glad it was able to work for you. In theory you should be able to do this with an external IP address (no different than say VNC or FTP to a remote computer). This of course requires knowledge of the external IP address. The easiest solution would be a DNS tracker. I have done this using nothing more than the sample code at the sites I listed although I have not had the opportunity to test it extensively as other aspects have been a priority. One important thing to note is the potential security risks of doing this...it either requires the firewall to forward the correct ports or no firewall..

Comment: at all. In this case SSH based commands might be a better way to go. Is this for a commercial app or personal use?

Comment: Thanks Jared.  This is a medical application, so it is commercial, but nothing that would be released in the public marketplace.  Fortunately configuring the firewall is not an issue since we tend to provide users with computers, rather than just the software we write.